# JQuery for Select Option affects all select option in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 select option in my html page.

I use JQuery for formatting one Select option using below code

```
$('select').wSelect();
```

but due to this , other select option also getting affected with the same formatting.

> I don't want JQuery to be applied on the second Select Option.

Could you please let me know how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give ID's to your selects!

```
<select id="sel1">
```

Then jQuery

```
$("#sel1").wSelect();
```

Answer (score 2):

Give your `select` you want to apply the formatting a class name, and then

```
$('select.wSelect').wSelect();
```

and in html:

```
<select class="wSelect">
   ...
</select>
```

So now, moving forward apply the class `wSelect` to all the `select` nodes which you want to apply the specific formatting to.

Comment: Applying a class that has no styling attributes to it sounds unnecessary. An ID seems a better way to IDentify what you want to select.

Comment: Well, i believe it is a more generic way of targetting. You do not have to create multiple `$('#..').wSelect()`, and this could be implemented as an application level implementation (Apply this class name to the select if you want the specific formatting) - I would implement this anyday as opposed to using IDs.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Also, I dont think styling attributes is required to be using a class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Specify a unique attribute like `id` to the `select` as below

```
<select id="sel">
```

and your code

```
$('select#sel ').wSelect();
```